# How can I force TSQL to accept two dates EQUAL if there is only an n miliseconds difference?

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, join, date-comparison

I have two tables, table1 and table2.

And I join them by comparing a couple of columns and one of them is a Date column.

```
select *
from table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.HaloDate = t2.HaloDate
```

My question is I found that the join fails for comparison of 2 dates below:

'2011-07-23 14:01:32.113' and '2011-07-23 14:01:32.114'

is it possible to write this join by ignoring the miliseconds or by introducing a range like 5 milisecons as a tolerance range?

Thanks

Comment: you could apply a function on both table1.HaloDate and table2.HaloDate but this will make your indexes worthless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
select *
from table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.HaloDate between dateadd(ms,-5,t2.HaloDate) and dateadd(ms,5,t2.HaloDate)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use DATEDIFF function and place into it any range you want, for example:

```
ABS(DATEDIFF(second, DateField1, DateField2)) < 5
```

means that date values difference less than 5 seconds.

You can use any tag for time range - from milliseconds to years